# Now with the coming of iOS 6 does apple still allow older facebook SDK?

Tags: ios, facebook

Like sdk version 3.0 for example?

Comment: Facebook SDK 3.0 is actually very new. Why would Apple not allow it?

Comment: 1. it uses an old JSon framework (I thought)
2. it's not optimized for iOS 6
3. DO you maybe know how to remove Json from the facebookSDK.bundle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I know of no restriction in the app store guidelines that says "Developers must not use any frameworks that are 'old'".
2. What do you mean by "optimized"?
3. Why do you want to do this? There's no good reason for it.

If the functionality you are looking for can be had with iOS 6's builtin support for Facebook sharing, and you don't need to target iOS5, use the built in stuff. Otherwise, go ahead and use the Facebook SDK, there's no reason not to.